# how to get `compile_commands.json` right for header-only library using cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm learning CMake and clangd, but I can't find a way to make CMake generate a proper `compile_commands.json` for clangd to parse third party libraries.

Here's what I've tried:

```
add_library(date_fmt INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(
  date_fmt INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
                     $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
target_sources(
  date_fmt
  INTERFACE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>/date_fmt/date_fmt.hpp
)
target_link_libraries(date_fmt INTERFACE date)
target_link_libraries(date_fmt INTERFACE fmt)
```

Comment: You don't have anything linking against `date_fmt` in your example, so there's nothing to compile.

Comment: @StephenNewell I know. The question here is whether there's a way to generate `compile_commands.json` for **the header-only library** without any source files. Since my goal is to write a header-only library, maybe no linking against `date_fmt` should happen?

Comment: Except `compile_commands.json` is used for things that are *compiled*.  Until you link against it, there's nothing to compile.

Comment: @StephenNewell All right, I get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sarcasm/compdb](https://github.com/Sarcasm/compdb) can generate a compilation database with header files.

just `pip install compdb` to install the software, then suppose you have a build directory called `build`, use `compdb -p build/ list > compile_commands.json` to generate the compile_commands.json.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33571779)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `compile_commands.json` is only used for things that are actually being compiled.  Since your `CMakeLists.txt` only creates an `INTERFACE` library and nothing uses it, there's no need to generate the compilation database.

Add something like this to your `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_executable(smoke_test smoke_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(smoke_test date_fmt)
```

`smoke_test.cpp` can be as simple as `int main() { return 0; }`, just something that'll compile.